# Decision table to decision tree using information gain

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, decision-tree

[image]

I have this decision table and I calculated the Information Gain for each attribute

```
q = 0
w = 0.083
e = 0.083
```

How should I draw the decision tree from it?

My idea is to have either w as a parent and q to be on the left side with e on the right as its children??